# Using a single application ID for retrieving hundreds of mailboxes from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm designing a web application that needs to retrieve and organize emails from at least 100 mailboxes from our company's domain. Something like:

abc@company.com
cde@company.com
efg@compnay.com
...

My web app needs to check each of these emails every couple of seconds to retrieve the new emails and index them. However, I don't want to hit the API limit for them.

Reading the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#outlook-service-limits), it seems like I can have a single app ID and use it to retrieve all these informations and won't hit the API limit.

If I have 100 mail boxes, and let's say, check each mailbox every 10 seconds (with maximum 4 concurrent threads), is it safe to say that I won't hit any kind of rate limit?

It might be worth mentioning that I'm going to use the [Delta Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview?tabs=http) feature to check for new emails. This will make things faster and I'm not sure if it has any effect on the rate limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to decrease the frequency of direct hits and only do that once you receive a notification from a particular mailbox/folder.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http for details on Graph event subscription.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about this. Actually, I'm writing a web app so this works perfectly. My question is, if I use this, could I still hit throttling limits?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so - subscribing to an event is like requesting a resource that take ages to respond and waiting until either some data is available (an event occurs) or the connection times out (tens of minutes), but no actual data is sent back and forth while waiting.